# Nativescript - error installing cocoapods after updating mac to catalina

Tags: cocoapods, nativescript

I can´t seem to find the problem, but definitely it has to do with the fact that i have done the following updates:

- Mac os version: 10.15.1 macOs catalina
- Xcode 11.2
- ios 13.2

  After this, i tried to run sidekick but it gave me errors, and i´ve passed through this before so i thought do the updates manually in my terminal but i´m stuck when i run this: 
  **sudo gem install cocoapods** or even without sudo, the error is always the same and i don´t know what to do:

  ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
      invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache/httpclient-2.8.3.gem

Help!

Thanks for your time

Comment: For anyone running on the same problem, the solution is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/42906.... the andyepx answer.